# Registration - sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

Django Version: 3.0.8 - Python Version: 3.7.8

I discovered an error on my Django site recently. When a user wants to create an account it returns this error:
sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Operation:

- account creation (check if username does not already exist on the DB)
- creation user Active = False
- sends an email for confirmation of account creation.

Error appears in the first step, the account is created (Active = False), no email is sent and error displayed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/eodj89/DjangoPro/user/views.py", line 45, in signup
    user.save()
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 795, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/eodj89/DjangoPro/user/models.py", line 479, in create_user_profile
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eodj89/virtualenv/DjangoPro/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/eodj89/DjangoPro/user/models.py", line 346, in save
    address = " ".join([self.full_address])

Exception Type: TypeError at /account/register/
Exception Value: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_address = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=128)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        
        address = " ".join([self.full_address])
        result = geocoder.geocode(address)

        if result and len(result):
            self.longitude = result[0]['geometry']['lng']
            self.latitude  = result[0]['geometry']['lat']
        
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what if full_address is None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify the error you see:

```
In [1]: ''.join([None])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-29122f69a077> in <module>
----> 1 ''.join([None])

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

In your case you get the same exception for this line:

```py
address = " ".join([self.full_address])
```

That means `self.full_address` is `None`.

In the meantime I don't think you need `join` there, because you try to join a single string. What are your expectations from that line?

So the code of your model will look like:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_address = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=128)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        
        if self.full_address:
            geo_code = geocoder.geocode(self.full_address)

            if geo_code:
                self.longitude = geo_code[0]['geometry']['lng']
                self.latitude  = geo_code[0]['geometry']['lat']
            
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your promptness Dmitry. What do you advise me to avoid this mistake, avoid None? Because as you know the Profile is used once the user is Active.

Comment: I would be happy to show you multiple ways on how to solve the problem. But I don't see the problem, I think you just don't need that `"".join(...)` at all - because there's nothing to join! :) So you can just remove that line.

Comment: And also there's a question to your requirements. Do you want that "full address" field be mandatory for all users? Or  maybe you want to give them a chance to skip that field during registration?

Comment: Ok so I'll remove it :) I think it's better if it's not compulsory.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that you have more code depending on that full address. You can't generate geo data as well if there's no address. So you should add a check like `if self.full_address: ...` and proceed with those geo calculations.

Comment: Something like self.full_address: more than x characters?

Comment: You are very welcome! If you think that my answer give you all the information you need - then please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well I just did it ;)